# Python - Identify String and integer from a string

Tags: python-3.x

Say for example you have a variable with a string which contains `x = '2 C'`, meaning 2 of clubs.

Is there a way of extracting the string **(c)** and storing it in a variable, i.e. **string_var**.

Then extract the number **(2)** into a different variable, i.e. **number_var**.

Comment: Is that structure permanent? Can there NOT be a space between them? Can they be in the reversed order? And most importantly, what have **you** tried to solve your problem?

Comment: I have tried to find the number in the string then I tried to remove from the string using var.remove() method but that didn’t work. My questions has now been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible, you just need to spilt the string:

```
x = '2 C'
y = x.split() # returns ["2", "C"]
number = y[0] # do int(y[0]) if you want it to be an int
card_type = y[1]
```

All that did was split the variable `x` by a space, then store the output in variables.